# Fetch columns values based on combobox selection changed in wpf datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, datagrid

I have a `WPF Datagrid` where one of the columns is a `DataGridComboBoxColumn`.
I need to change some columns values based on the selected item in this Combobox.
Below is the `xaml` code:

```
    <DataGrid Name="dgInvDetails" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
             <mui:DataGridTextColumn Header="ID"  Binding="{Binding ID}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
             <mui:DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Item Description" x:Name="DdlItems" IsReadOnly="True" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Description}"
SelectedValuePath="ItemID"
DisplayMemberPath="Description">
                   <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                         <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                              <EventSetter Event="SelectionChanged" Handler="ItemSelectionChanged" />
                          </Style>
                   </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
              </mui:DataGridComboBoxColumn>
              <mui:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="TextQuantity" Header="Quatity" Binding="{Binding Quatity}" IsReadOnly="True" />
              <mui:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="TextUnitPrice" Header="Unit Price" Binding="{Binding UnitPrice}" IsReadOnly="True" />
         </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

So when the user changes the selection of the item Combobox, I need to set some specific values in the `TextUnitPrice`.

I created the following method on server side:

```
private void ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        InvoiceDetails selectedItem = this.dgInvDetails.CurrentItem as InvoiceDetails;
        // Getting the invoice detail from DB
        // Setting the invoice detail unit price to TextUnitPrice
    }
```

So how can i access the other text boxes and set the values in them for the selected row?

Comment: Why not just catch Description change in model itself and change UnitPrice there as well?

Comment: How can i catch the Description change in the model? If you mean in the ItemSelectionChanged method, yes this is what I am doing, but I don't know how to access the TextUnitPrice text box for the same selected row.

Comment: No, what I mean is that every column is bound to some property of some custom type. So when you change Description property, there's a setter that's get called, and you can change UnitPrice there. If you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged correctly, UI will reflect that change.

Comment: This will work outside the datagrid. Because in my case, I need to access the UnitPrice  text box only for the "selected row". So I just need to set a value for the unit price only for the selected row where the items combo is changed.